# Text in body (Basic Page) not displayed

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I'm having trouble displaying the body text when creating a Basic Page. I've somehow deleted the body field at some point and then tried to add existing field again.

Now that I've added Body field again and typing in some text in the body for a Basic Page, it won't appear on my page. I can see my text in `body_value` in myphpadmin in `field_data_body` and my page is only displaying the title.

I've tried several things. Cleared cache, reapplied all template files (page.tlp.php etc.)

Im using Drupal 7.

Any help appreciated

Comment: You have 2 options: check node.tpl.php file and check the content displayed. Or Changing the content type display fields settings. Could you try this?

Comment: The machine name should be body (if you don't want to modify your node template) So when you want to put back the field select it from existing fields: Go to Add existing field, select Long text and summary: body(Body).